# Volley Kotlin Coroutine throws CompilationException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-coroutines

I need to retreive various JSONObjects from an API using Volley. The API requires header authentication using Basic. It works if I don't add the headers but when I do I keep getting a `org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException`. Here are the functions I wrote:

```
private suspend fun readData(url: String): JSONObject = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val request: JsonObjectRequest = object: JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
        continuation.resume(it)
    }, Response.ErrorListener {
        continuation.resumeWithException(Exception(it.cause))
    }) {
        override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> = mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json", "charset" to "utf-8", "Authorization" to "Basic ".plus(android.util.Base64.encode(String.format("%s:%s", getString(R.string.api_login_username), getString(R.string.api_login_password)).toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)))
    }
    request.setShouldCache(false)
    this.queue?.add(request)
}


fun data(url: String) = async(CommonPool) { readData(url) }
```

And them implement them like so:

```
val brands = data(getString(R.string.api_url).plus("/api/brand"))
val models = data(getString(R.string.api_url).plus("/api/model"))

launch(UI) {
    val brandsJsonArray = brands.await().getJSONArray("recordset")
    val modelsJsonArray = models.await().getJSONArray("recordset")
}
```

But this is the exception I keep getting once I try to compile the project:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't inline method call 'suspendCoroutine' into
    public final suspend fun readData(queue: com.android.volley.RequestQueue?, url: kotlin.String, continuation: kotlin.coroutines.experimental.Continuation<org.json.JSONObject>): kotlin.Any? defined in com.universales.inspeccion.activities.InspectionCreateActivity
    suspend fun readData(url: String): JSONObject = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
            val request = object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, JSONObject(), Response.Listener {
                continuation.resume(it)
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                continuation.resumeWithException(Exception(it.cause))
            }) {
                override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> = mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/json", "charset" to "utf-8", "Authorization" to "Basic ".plus(android.util.Base64.encode(String.format("%s:%s", getString(R.string.api_login_username), getString(R.string.api_login_password)).toByteArray(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT)))
            }
            queue?.add(request)
            continuation.invokeOnCompletion {
                request.cancel()
            }
        }
    Cause: suspendCancellableCoroutine$default (ZLkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation;ILjava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
       L0
       L1
        LINENUMBER 167 L1
        ICONST_0
        ISTORE 0
       L2
        LINENUMBER 297 L2
        ICONST_0
        INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/InlineMarker.mark (I)V
        ALOAD 2
        INVOKESTATIC kotlin/coroutines/experimental/jvm/internal/CoroutineIntrinsics.normalizeContinuation (Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation;)Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation;
        ASTORE 4
       L3
        LINENUMBER 298 L3
        NEW kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CancellableContinuationImpl
        DUP
        ALOAD 4
        ICONST_1
        INVOKESPECIAL kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CancellableContinuationImpl.<init> (Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation;I)V
        ASTORE 5
       L4
        LINENUMBER 299 L4
        ILOAD 0
        IFNE L5
        ALOAD 5
        INVOKEVIRTUAL kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CancellableContinuationImpl.initCancellability ()V
       L5
        LINENUMBER 300 L5
        ALOAD 1
        ALOAD 5
        INVOKEINTERFACE kotlin/jvm/functions/Function1.invoke (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        POP
       L6
        LINENUMBER 301 L6
        ALOAD 5
        INVOKEVIRTUAL kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CancellableContinuationImpl.getResult ()Ljava/lang/Object;
       L7
        NOP
       L8
        LINENUMBER 297 L8
        ICONST_1
        INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/InlineMarker.mark (I)V
       L9
        LINENUMBER 302 L9
        ARETURN
       L10
        LOCALVARIABLE cancellable Lkotlinx/coroutines/experimental/CancellableContinuationImpl; L4 L7 5
        LOCALVARIABLE cont Lkotlin/coroutines/experimental/Continuation; L3 L8 4
        LOCALVARIABLE $i$a$2$suspendCoroutineOrReturn I L3 L8 6
        LOCALVARIABLE holdCancellability Z L2 L10 0
        LOCALVARIABLE block Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1; L0 L10 1
        LOCALVARIABLE $i$f$suspendCancellableCoroutine I L2 L10 3
        MAXSTACK = 4
        MAXLOCALS = 7

    Cause: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    File being compiled at position: (124,75) in C:/Users/jcardama/Projects/android/inspeccion/app/src/main/java/com/universales/inspeccion/activities/InspectionCreateActivity.kt
    The root cause was thrown at: MethodInliner.kt:280
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.throwCompilationException(InlineCodegen.kt:124)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:167)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCallInner(InlineCodegen.kt:661)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CallGenerator$DefaultImpls.genCall(CallGenerator.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.PsiInlineCodegen.genCall(InlineCodegen.kt:642)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2398)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.invokeMethodWithArguments(ExpressionCodegen.java:2347)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:41)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.Callable$invokeMethodWithArguments$1.invoke(Callable.kt:13)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.OperationStackValue.putSelector(StackValue.kt:79)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:109)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.StackValue.put(StackValue.java:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.putStackValue(ExpressionCodegen.java:349)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.gen(ExpressionCodegen.java:334)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ExpressionCodegen.returnExpression(ExpressionCodegen.java:1621)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.SuspendFunctionGenerationStrategy.doGenerateBody(SuspendFunctionGenerationStrategy.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionGenerationStrategy$CodegenBased.generateBody(FunctionGenerationStrategy.java:80)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:620)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethodBody(FunctionCodegen.java:391)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:244)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generateMethod(FunctionCodegen.java:168)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.FunctionCodegen.gen(FunctionCodegen.java:139)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genSimpleMember(MemberCodegen.java:199)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateDeclaration(ClassBodyCodegen.java:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.ClassBodyCodegen.generateBody(ClassBodyCodegen.java:75)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.generate(MemberCodegen.java:131)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:305)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.MemberCodegen.genClassOrObject(MemberCodegen.java:289)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassOrObject(PackageCodegenImpl.java:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateClassesAndObjectsInFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:86)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generateFile(PackageCodegenImpl.java:119)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.PackageCodegenImpl.generate(PackageCodegenImpl.java:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generatePackage(CodegenFactory.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.DefaultCodegenFactory.generateModule(CodegenFactory.kt:68)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:454)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:150)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:161)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:96)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:463)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:228)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:38)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:90)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:102)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:538)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:418)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:920)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:950)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:417)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.visitMethodInsn(MethodInliner.kt:280)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode.accept(MethodInsnNode.java:133)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:162)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:817)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:351)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.access$doInline(MethodInliner.kt:39)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner$doInline$lambdaInliner$1.visitMethodInsn(MethodInliner.kt:259)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodInsnNode.accept(MethodInsnNode.java:133)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.InsnList.accept(InsnList.java:162)
        at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(MethodNode.java:817)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:351)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:93)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.MethodInliner.doInline(MethodInliner.kt:66)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.inlineCall(InlineCodegen.kt:278)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.inline.InlineCodegen.performInline(InlineCodegen.kt:158)
        ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Push out the definition of `object: JsonObjectRequest` to a named class that takes the continuation as a constructor parameter. This way you'll make the code inside `suspendCancellableCoroutine` simpler and avoid this compiler bug.

```
suspend fun readData(url: String): JSONObject = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    RequestWithHeaders(url, continuation).also {
        it.setShouldCache(false)
        queue.add(it)
    }
}

class RequestWithHeaders(
        url: String,
        continuation: Continuation<JSONObject>
) : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, Response.Listener {
    continuation.resume(it)
}, Response.ErrorListener {
    continuation.resumeWithException(Exception(it.cause))
}) {
    override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> = mapOf(
            "Content-Type" to "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "Authorization" to "Basic")
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue.  
Was able to fix it by creating the params map as a separate variable and using it inside `getParams`. Why is the kotlin compiler so bad?

Comment: Thanks. It would be better if this answer has a reference to the bug ticket.